# SilverStripe frontend Ajax blog post loading with 'read more' button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, silverstripe

I am using the SilverStripe frontend module for Ajax loading of each blog entry on the blog holder page. The only problem is I am getting a JS issue with the actual JS file provided in the module.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sspagination' of undefined

this runs on the first line I believe of the JS file for the code:

```
$.widget("ss.ssendless", $.ss.sspagination, {
```

is this my fault? is this common?

Also when I run the jQuery it says to run, so I can initiate the AJAX loading, I get another console error. The code it is asking me to run is:

```
$('div.pagination').ssendless({
    contentSelector: '.pagination-content',
    indicatorElement: $('.pagination-indicator')
});
```

and the error i get with this is

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ssendless is not a function

this runs on the first line of my jQuery

```
$('div.pagination').ssendless({
```

If this issue is not one you can fix, could you recommend another SS module that will help me achieve the AJAX endless loading of blog entries from the blog holder page instead of the standard numbered pagination?

Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0):

At this point in time the current [SilverStripe Frontend module](https://github.com/mateusz/silverstripe-frontend) does not work with the latest [SilverStripe Blog module](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-blog/).

The Blog module recently had a major upgrade, which changed a lot of it's code. This version is currently the master branch.

You can download an older version of the Blog module by dowloading the [1.0 branch](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-blog/tree/1.0/). This version should work with the Frontend module, although it's not as nice as the current version.